# Chart.js min max not working, can not disable scaling as values change

Tags: charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a static chart with two moving points. I can not figure out the way how to force the chart not to scale as my values are changing and at a same time have given values of 520-780 for yaxis and 21-37 on the x axis.

This is my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: "Mass & Balance Envelope",
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)",
            titleFontSize: 16,
            bodyFontSize: 14
          },
          display: false,
          scales: {
            x: [{
              type: 'linear',
              position: 'bottom',
              ticks: {
                min: 21,
                max: 37
              }
            }],
            y: [{
              type: 'linear',
              position: 'left',
              ticks: {
                min: 520,
                max: 780
              }
            }]
          }
        }      
  });

setInterval(function() {
    var dot1_x = vypocet_vahy_lietadla_funkcia();
    var dot1_y = vypocet_pozicie_taziska_SAT_funkcia();
    var dot2_x = vypocet_vahy_lietadla_0fuel_funkcia();
    var dot2_y = vypocet_pozicie_taziska_SAT_0fuel_funkcia();
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = [
        {x: dot1_y, y: dot1_x, label: "TO Weight and Balance"},
        {x: dot2_y, y: dot2_x, label: "0 Fuel Weight and Balance"}    
    ];
    chart.update();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If you are using chart.js 4, the scale options are wrongly configured. The scales (x and y) are defined as an array but they should be an object. And in this case, chart.js is suing the default ones, without min and max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it as I'm using Chart.js 4+

```js
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)",
      titleFontSize: 16,
      bodyFontSize: 14
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        suggestedMin: 21,
        suggestedMax: 37
      },
      y: {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        suggestedMin: 520,
        suggestedMax: 780
      }
    }
  },
```